# Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless is fluctuating

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm trying use my internet and I've been connected with a cord for a month now. I've been looking everywhere to find the answer to my problem, but they won't work. I have a realtek wireless router. When I try to use my wireless, it goes to crap. It is very very slow. When I try to use my wireless, it fluctuates from not working, to a really slow internet speed. My phone, and my other computer works fine, and the other one has windows. So it has to be a Linux problem. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04,Co

Results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07) 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2190] 
    Kernel driver in use: r8169 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of WiFi adapter your computer is using? If you have a laptop, there might be info about your WiFi adapter on the bottom. If your adapter is USB, it might say somewhere on the USB device itself.

Comment: Add the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to your question

Comment: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2190]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197d]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple fixes, option 1 is `echo "options rtl8188ee ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf` and reboot, if no improvement we can install backports

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

If you install updates and notice the same issue with wifi, it is likely caused by a kernel update, then you need to

```
cd backports
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot